# regex101.com task 8 Strip all HTML tags from a string

Tags: regex

I'm taking the regex101.com quiz and am stuck on task 8.

The request:
Strip all HTML tags from a string. HTML tags are enclosed in < and >.

I tried, </?\w*+\s?/?>, but it says

"Test 6 of 13 failed:
You are overusing greedy quantifiers. For example, in the string "ace" you are returning "ae" when you should be returning "ace"."

However, http://rubular.com/r/CD2zJjSFgs seems to works.  How do I prevent it from being greedy?

Comment: Try again, I have added a test that should help you on the way.

Answer (score 1):

Use a complemented character class:

```
<[^>]+>
```

Comment: Same error from the site.  "You are overusing greedy quantifiers"

Comment: Well, the site sucks, honestly. This solution works fine, and is better than using a lazy quantifier.

Comment: I've been spending all day trying to solve many of these and they seem very inconsistent.

Comment: Trust rubular ;) That is, if you use Ruby as a regex engine... Or buy "Mastering Regular Expressions" ;)

Comment: OK, the other reason is that you forgot to use the `g` modifier. This will at least get you to the 10th test case.

Comment: @fge: That's not a very nice thing to say really. I've put down a lot of hard work on my website and merely forgot a simple test case for the `/g` modifier which is the reason for the unrelated error. This took me however 2 minutes to fix, and would have been fixed without any fuss if you or anyone else had just sent me an email about it instead of complaining. Luckily an awesome member already did and informed me about it, which is the only reason I'm seeing this and the problem is fixed. My email is in the site footer for future reference.

Comment: @Lindrian the problem is that there are many solutions to one problem using regexes and the only real solution is to take sample text and run the regex through it. What is more, a regex engine using / as a delimiter is assumed along with the appropriate flags... As a seasoned regex practitioner (I even taught regexes at my work), this is quite a setback ;)

Comment: @fge: if you are as seasoned as you claim you would know that perl regexes (including pcre) work with practically any delimiter. / is however considered standard. Why and how is this limiting? The quiz allows for any solution that satisfies all conditions. However, some solutions _are_ better than others and it is those I am trying to teach. These sre in many cases constructs you can apply in many cases.

Comment: @Lindrian I also use regex engines which don't need a delimiter at all ;) Regex engines for which `\d` matches Unicode digits and others for which it doesn't etc

Comment: @fge: The delimiter is irrelevant. Practially all work with or without them (including perl). Its there for the users convenience. Whats your point about that? Perl matches unicode too. Most modern engines do.

Comment: Didn't mean to start an argument.  Lindrian,did put a lot of hard work into it, but as with any new site, it has some bugs and he's fixing them.  thanks for the hard work and good resource!

Answer (score 1):

I tried the site myself, and it was pretty crappy at first with 4-5 tasks with bugs in test case, but I emailed the admin and he fixed all of them. Currently, I have completed all the tasks available - which means that all the tasks are doable. The only possible bug is that the test case are too narrow that a less general regex can pass, but this doesn't have anything to do with the problem at hand.

The answer by @willOEM and @fge, and even your answer will work correctly up to test case 8 (blocked at test case 9 due to empty tag, whether empty tag actually needs removing or not is debatable, though) or test case 9 (blocked at test case 10 due to additional requirement), ***if the `g` flag is specified***. Without it, you are only removing one tag in test case 6.

Comment: Is there a way to private message you?

Comment: Thanks for messaging me about the errors on the site. As soon as someone does, I get to fixing. It's not easy thinking of all the possible cases yourself... there are many. And some of the tasks or requirements may seem odd or "weird", but this is for practice. You are meant to learn how to use proper constructs etc.

Comment: @nhahtdh Is there a way to message you privately?

Comment: @nhahtdh I reviewed your profile. might have a freelance project, if interested.

Answer (score 0):

Would it consider this less greedy?

```
<.+?>
```

Comment: I second @fge, the test is crap.  `...in the string "a<b>c<d>e" you are returning "ae" when you should be returning "ace".`  No it wouldn't, this regex works!!!